# Problems with NVIDIA & X11 & Debian

Tags: debian, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card

My NVIDIA GT440 doesn't work with current Debian Squeeze - it shows only 1024x768 as max.

I did almost everything like

1. xrandr
2. xorg.conf (delete, creating etc.)
3. download the NVIDIA driver from NV (doesn't work)
4. objdump nouveau etc driver/libs (they're lookin ok)
5. substituting the drivers/libs from SystemRescue CD to my installation
6. using correct params for my LCD

What me wonders: On the SystemRescue the resolution eg. 1440x900 works - Wonder why??

Please could some Linux X11-Server Guru help me (I hope no compilation of nouveau is required) ;-)))

Comment: What do you mean by "download the NVIDIA driver from NV (won't work)"? That is probably your best option.

Comment: Also, please post your xorg.conf.

Comment: The Nvidia driver doesn't install (an already known problem) - even if I force it (maybe different version of libs). And for the Xorg.conf. I haven't anyone at first then I used this one: http://lists.debian.org/debian-amd64/2008/05/msg00154.html . It still doesn't work

Comment: Just to share my own experience: When I used multiple solutions (`apt` installation and nvidia's own package), it turned out that some conflicts happened that I could not fix. Therefore, I reinstalled my debian and installed the driver from nvidia web site and it is working now (fresh install+closing the x completely).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can try. First of all, as a general rule, if you choose an xorg.conf file from the depths of the internet, don't pick one that is posted on a thread about how the xorg.conf file is not working as expected :).

Try the following steps:

1. Add your screen resolution to the xorg.conf file. The one you posted has no entry for 1440x900. Makes sure one of the "Modes" is "1440x900".
2. Most of that xorg.conf file is irrelevant or just plain wrong for your hardware, try a barebones xorg.conf, something like:

   ```
   Section "Device"
       Identifier     "Device0"
       Driver         "nouveau"
       VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
       BoardName      "NVIDIA GT440"
   EndSection

   Section "Screen"
       Identifier      "Screen0"
       Device          "Device0"
       EndSubSection
       SubSection "Display"
               Depth           24
               Modes           "1440x900"
       EndSubSection
   EndSection
   ```
3. Create an xorg.conf file for your system. Log out of your session, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> to drop to a tty. Log in with your username and password, then do:

   ```
   sudo Xorg -configure
   ```

   That will create a new xorg.conf file saved as `/root/xorg.conf.new`. Copy that to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and resstart the X server.
4. Make sure the correct drivers are loaded. If you are using the nouveau driver, run `sudo modprobe nouveau`.
5. Try and install the nvidia driver again. Alternatively, post a new question with the error message you receive. The general procedure should be:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install module-assistant nvidia-kernel-common
   sudo m-a auto-install nvidia-kernel${VERSION}-source
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-kernel-dkms nvidia-settings nvidia-xconfig
   sudo nvidia-xconfig
   ```