# unable to load X after installing NVIDIA in debian

Tags: linux, debian, graphics-card, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card

I just installed my NVIDIA graphics card driver using [this manual](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers), but after installation my X does not load. I login using terminal and remove the `xorg.config` and access the safe mode. Is there any problem or is it a bug?

I tried [Problems with NVIDIA & X11 & Debian](https://superuser.com/questions/533193/problems-with-nvidia-x11-debian/536580#536580) answer but it didn't work.

I used `sudo Xorg -configure` and I got the following log:

```
[     4.886] 
X.Org X Server 1.12.4
Release Date: 2012-08-27
[     4.886] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[     4.886] Build Operating System: Linux 3.11-2-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[     4.886] Current Operating System: Linux pdebian 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.63-2+deb7u1 x86_64
[     4.886] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=54830b4d-ac55-4f3c-8e01-0d8e8825b997 ro quiet
[     4.886] Build Date: 17 December 2013  07:37:58PM
[     4.886] xorg-server 2:1.12.4-6+deb7u2 (Julien Cristau <jcristau@debian.org>) 
[     4.886] Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
[     4.886]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[     4.886] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     4.887] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Nov  8 23:23:19 2014
[     4.889] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[     4.897] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[     4.897] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[     4.897] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[     4.897] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[     4.897] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[     4.897] (==) Automatically adding devices
[     4.897] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[     4.900] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     4.900]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     4.916] (WW) The directory "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType" does not exist.
[     4.916]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     4.916] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[     4.916] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[     4.916] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[     4.916] (II) Loader magic: 0x7f6c1aaf1ae0
[     4.916] (II) Module ABI versions:
[     4.916]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[     4.916]    X.Org Video Driver: 12.1
[     4.916]    X.Org XInput driver : 16.0
[     4.916]    X.Org Server Extension : 6.0
[     4.917] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:063a:1028:019b rev 161, Mem @ 0xf5000000/16777216, 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf2000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000df00/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[     4.917] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[     4.917] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
[     4.917] (II) "extmod" will be loaded by default.
[     4.917] (II) "dbe" will be loaded by default.
[     4.917] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[     4.917] (II) "record" will be loaded by default.
[     4.917] (II) "dri" will be loaded by default.
[     4.917] (II) "dri2" will be loaded by default.
[     4.917] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[     4.923] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
[     4.926] (II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.926]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.0.0
[     4.926]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[     4.926]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[     4.926] (II) Loading extension SELinux
[     4.926] (II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[     4.926] (II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[     4.926] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
[     4.926] (II) Loading extension DPMS
[     4.926] (II) Loading extension XVideo
[     4.926] (II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[     4.927] (II) Loading extension X-Resource
[     4.927] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
[     4.927] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
[     4.928] (II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.929]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.0.0
[     4.929]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[     4.929]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[     4.929] (II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[     4.929] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     4.929] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[     4.933] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.933]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.0.0
[     4.933]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[     4.933] (==) AIGLX enabled
[     4.936] (II) Loading extension GLX
[     4.936] (II) LoadModule: "record"
[     4.936] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
[     4.937] (II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.937]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.13.0
[     4.937]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[     4.937]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[     4.937] (II) Loading extension RECORD
[     4.937] (II) LoadModule: "dri"
[     4.938] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
[     4.940] (II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.940]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.0.0
[     4.940]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[     4.940] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
[     4.940] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[     4.940] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[     4.942] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.942]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.2.0
[     4.942]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[     4.942] (II) Loading extension DRI2
[     4.942] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 0
[     4.942] (==) Matched nv as autoconfigured driver 1
[     4.942] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
[     4.942] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[     4.942] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[     4.942] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[     4.943] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[     4.946] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.946]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.0.1
[     4.946]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     4.946]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 12.1
[     4.946] (II) LoadModule: "nv"
[     4.949] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nv
[     4.949] (II) UnloadModule: "nv"
[     4.949] (II) Unloading nv
[     4.949] (EE) Failed to load module "nv" (module does not exist, 0)
[     4.949] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[     4.949] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[     4.950] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.950]    compiled for 1.12.1, module version = 2.3.1
[     4.950]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     4.950]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 12.0
[     4.950] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[     4.950] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[     4.951] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.951]    compiled for 1.12.1, module version = 0.4.2
[     4.951]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 12.0
[     4.951] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Fri Jul 6 16:23:50 2012 +1000
[     4.951] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[     4.951]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[     4.951]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[     4.951]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[     4.952]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[     4.952]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[     4.952]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[     4.952]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[     4.952]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[     4.952]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[     4.952]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[     4.952]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[     4.952]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[     4.952]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
[     4.952] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[     4.952] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[     4.952] (++) using VT number 7

[     4.972] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[     4.977] [drm] failed to load kernel module "nouveau"
[     4.977] (EE) [drm] failed to open device
[     4.977] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[     4.977] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[     4.977] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[     4.977] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[     4.978] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.978]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 0.0.2
[     4.978]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 12.1
[     4.978] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[     4.979] (II) Loading sub module "vbe"
[     4.979] (II) LoadModule: "vbe"
[     4.979] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libvbe.so
[     4.979] (II) Module vbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.980]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.1.0
[     4.980]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 12.1
[     4.980] (II) Loading sub module "int10"
[     4.980] (II) LoadModule: "int10"
[     4.980] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libint10.so
[     4.982] (II) Module int10: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.982]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.0.0
[     4.982]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 12.1
[     4.982] (II) VESA(0): initializing int10
[     4.983] (II) VESA(0): Primary V_BIOS segment is: 0xc000
[     5.035] (II) VESA(0): VESA BIOS detected
[     5.035] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE Version 3.0
[     5.035] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE Total Mem: 14336 kB
[     5.035] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM: NVIDIA
[     5.035] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Software Rev: 98.148
[     5.035] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
[     5.035] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Product: G94 Board - nike94  
[     5.035] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Product Rev: Chip Rev   
[     5.131] (II) VESA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[     5.131] (==) VESA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[     5.131] (==) VESA(0): RGB weight 888
[     5.131] (==) VESA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[     5.131] (==) VESA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[     5.131] (II) Loading sub module "ddc"
[     5.131] (II) LoadModule: "ddc"
[     5.131] (II) Module "ddc" already built-in
[     5.204] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC supported
[     5.204] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC Level none
[     5.204] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC transfer in appr. 0 sec.
[     5.498] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC read failed
[     5.588] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE PanelID read successfully
[     5.588] (II) VESA(0): PanelID returned panel resolution 1920x1200
[     5.588] (II) VESA(0): Searching for matching VESA mode(s):
...
```

I tried installation of the packages recommended but I got the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install module-assistant nvidia-kernel-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
module-assistant is already the newest version.
nvidia-kernel-common is already the newest version.
nvidia-kernel-common set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 890 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Setting up glx-alternative-nvidia (0.5.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative link /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so is already managed by x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf
dpkg: error processing package glx-alternative-nvidia (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-kernel-common:
 nvidia-kernel-common depends on glx-alternative-nvidia (>= 0.3); however:
  Package glx-alternative-nvidia is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-kernel-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 glx-alternative-nvidia
 nvidia-kernel-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a package incompatibility in debian repositories.

To solve this problem, I inverted all the changes and then downloaded the driver from nvidia web site and installed it from terminal.